# How to do a multi-value filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code:

```
class PageListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ('category', 'calculated_hsk')
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    ordering_fields = ['date']
```

My category value is an integer.

I am calling my local API as such:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/pages/?category=1,6&calculated_hsk__in=4.00&limit=10&ordering=-date&offset=0

However this does not work

I have also tried

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/pages/?category__in=1,6&calculated_hsk__in=4.00&limit=10&ordering=-date&offset=0

Which likewise doesn't work.

Is there a specific filter backend I need?

I am trying to replicate this aspect of a query:

```
WHERE category IN (value1, value2, ...)
```

Comment: I guess this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203259/django-filter-multiple-url-parameters

Comment: Are you using django-filters?

Comment: @rob Yes I am using django-filters

Comment: @rob I tried putting in     filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, filters.BaseInFilter) but to no avail

Comment: The answer I typically use is something like whats provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/djangofilterbackend-with-multiple-ids

Comment: @rob Hrm, so with my usecase, would I just write class NumberInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.NumberFilter):
    pass and then do something like filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, NumberInFilter)?