# Reload choices dynamically when using MultipleChoiceFilter

Tags: django, django-filters, multiplechoicefield, modelmultiplechoicefield

I am trying to construct a `MultipleChoiceFilter` where the choices are the set of possible dates that exist on a related model (`DatedResource`).

Here is what I am working with so far...

```
resource_date = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
    field_name='dated_resource__date',
    choices=[
        (d, d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for d in
        sorted(resource_models.DatedResource.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True).distinct())
    ],
    label="Resource Date"
)
```

When this is displayed in a html view...

[image]

This works fine at first, however if I create new `DatedResource` objects with new distinct `date` values I need to re-launch my webserver in order for them to get picked up as a valid choice in this filter. I believe this is because the `choices` list is evaluated once when the webserver starts up, not every time my page loads.

Is there any way to get around this? Maybe through some creative use of a `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried some simple `ModelMultipleChoice` usage, but hitting some issues.

```
resource_date = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    field_name='dated_resource__date',
    queryset=resource_models.DatedResource.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True).order_by('date').distinct(),
    label="Resource Date"
)
```

The HTML form is showing up just fine, however the choices are not accepted values to the filter. I get `"2019-04-03" is not a valid value.` validation errors, I am assuming because this filter is expecting `datetime.date` objects. I thought about using the `coerce` parameter, however those are not accepted in `ModelMultipleChoice` filters.

Per dirkgroten's comment, I tried to use what was suggested in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210217/how-to-use-modelmultiplechoicefilter). This ends up being something like

```
resource_date = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    field_name='dated_resource__date',
    to_field_name='date',
    queryset=resource_models.DatedResource.objects.all(),
    label="Resource Date"
)
```

This also isnt what I want, as the HTML now form is now a) displaying the `str` representation of each `DatedResource`, instead of the `DatedResource.date` field and b) they are not unique (ex if I have two `DatedResource` objects with the same `date`, both of their `str` representations appear in the list. This also isnt sustainable because I have 200k+ `DatedResources`, and the page hangs when attempting to load them all (as compared to the `values_list` filter, which is able to pull all distinct dates out in seconds.

Comment: you're already giving the answer yourself, use a `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210217/how-to-use-modelmultiplechoicefilter).

Comment: @dirkgroten Added an addendum with some `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` thoughts. I'm almost there, just feel like I'm missing a crucial piece

Comment: I fail to see why this is not covered by using a callable that returns whatever you want as your `choices` parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the easy solutions will be ***overriding the `__init__()` method of the filterset class***.

```
from django_filters import filters, filterset


class FooFilter(filterset.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.filters['user'].extra['choices'] = [(d, d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for d in sorted(
                resource_models.DatedResource.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True).distinct())]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass

    resource_date = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='dated_resource__date', choices=[], label="Resource Date")
```

**NOTE:** provide **`choices=[]`** in your field definition of filterset class

---

## Results

**I tested and verified this solution with following dependencies**
1. Python 3.6
2. Django 2.1
3. DRF 3.8.2
4. django-filter 2.0.0
**I used following code to reproduce the behaviour**

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} : {self.artist}'


# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Album


# filters.py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class AlbumFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['release_date'].extra['choices'] = self.get_album_filter_choices()

    def get_album_filter_choices(self):
        release_date_list = Album.objects.values_list('release_date', flat=True).distinct()
        return [(date, date) for date in release_date_list]

    release_date = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=[])

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('release_date',)


# views.py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class AlbumViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = AlbumFilter
```

Here I've used the **`django-filter`** with **`DRF`**.
Now, I populated some data through Django Admin console. After that, the album api become as below,
[image: Album-List API Result]
and I got the **`release_date`** as 
[image: DateChoices Before]
Then, [I added new entry through Django admin -- (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnY4a.png) and I refresh the DRF API endpoint and the possible choices became as below,
[image: New Choice in FilterList]

Answer (score 2):

I have looked into your problem and I have following suggestions

**The Problem**

You have got the problem right. Choices for your `MultipleChoiceFilter` are calculated statically whenever you run server.Thats why they don't get updated dynamically whenever you insert new instance in `DatedResource`.

To get it working correctly, you have to provide choices dynamically to `MultipleChoiceFilter`. I searched in documentation but did not find anything regarding this. So here is my solution.

**The solution**

You have to extend `MultipleChoiceFilter` and create your own filter class. I have created this and here it is.

```
from typing import Callable
from django_filters.conf import settings
import django_filters


class LazyMultipleChoiceFilter(django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter):
    def get_field_choices(self):
        choices = self.extra.get('choices', [])
        if isinstance(choices, Callable):
            choices = choices()
        return choices

    @property
    def field(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_field'):
            field_kwargs = self.extra.copy()

            if settings.DISABLE_HELP_TEXT:
                field_kwargs.pop('help_text', None)

            field_kwargs.update(choices=self.get_field_choices())

            self._field = self.field_class(label=self.label, **field_kwargs)
        return self._field
```

Now you can use this class as replacement and pass choices as lambda function like this.

```
resource_date = LazyMultipleChoiceFilter(
    field_name='dated_resource__date',
    choices=lambda: [
        (d, d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for d in
        sorted(resource_models.DatedResource.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True).distinct())
    ],
    label="Resource Date"
)
```

Whenever instance of filter will be created choices will be updated dynamically. You can also pass choices statically (without lambda function) to this field if want default behavior.