# How to use model objects as choices for django-filter MultipleChoiceFilter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter, django-2.x

I'm using Django-filter, and I would like one of the fields (`supervisor`) to be a `ChoiceFilter` where the choices are objects from the model. What's the most efficient way to do that? I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496921/reload-choices-dynamically-when-using-multiplechoicefilter), but kept getting errors no matter what I changed (currently `cannot unpack non-iterable int object`).

```
# models.py
class people(models.Model):
    namelast = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name')
    namefirst = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name')
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Supervisor')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.namefirst, self.namelast)

# filters.py
class office_filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    supervisor = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=[], lookup_expr='icontains', label='Supervisor')
    # other fields

    class Meta:
        model = people
        fields = ['namelast', 'namefirst', 'supervisor']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.filters['supervisor'].extra['choices'] = [x for x in
                people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct()]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass
```

The goal is to have the `supervisor` field be a nice menu of all of the people that have been added assigned as a supervisor in the `people` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ananya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702793/5900093) helped me get on the correct track of what have that statement return, but after thinking about the errors and how choice lists are usually constructed, I realized I needed it to return a tuple (not just a value). Here is the relevant code that ended up working:

```
class office_filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    supervisor = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=[], label='Supervisor')
    #...
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                self.filters['supervisor'].extra['choices'] = [(people.objects.get(pk=x).id, people.objects.get(pk=x)) for x in people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct() if x is not None]
            except (KeyError, AttributeError):
                pass
```

The important part being: `(people.objects.get(pk=x).id, people.objects.get(pk=x))` rather than just `people.objects.get(pk=x)`.

Also had to remove `lookup_expr` in the filter field.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a 100% sure, but could you try something?

```
[people.objects.get(pk=x[0]) for x in people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct()]
```

or

```
[people.objects.get(id=x[0]) for x in people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct()]
```

In the link that you mentioned I believe
`DatedResource.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True).distinct())`
returns an array of string

In your code
`people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct()` 
would return a string of int - the IDs of the records as it is a Foreign Key

Comment: That's good to know about what's returned from the link I posted. Unfortunately both versions of your suggestion give the error `int object is not subscriptable`, so I tried `pk=x` and got `cannot unpack non-iterable people object`. That whole line works okay in the shell, so I wonder if it's django-filter not liking whatever list is returned (not clear in error messages).

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out...it has to return a tuple. `[(people.objects.get(pk=x).id, people.objects.get(pk=x)) for x in people.objects.all().values_list('supervisor', flat=True).distinct() if x is not None]` seems to be working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!