# How can i receive the array send in url in django REST

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want send  list of ids via Django REST framework.

in my Angular Javascript code

I have             `ids = [1, 2, 3 ,4]`

But in my url it gets sends as

`ids=1&ids=2`

In my Django filter i get the last `ids=4`

I want to get the all ids. How can i get that

I am using django Filters

```
class IntegerListFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self,qs,value):
        if value not in (None,''):
            integers = [int(v) for v in value.split(',')]
            return qs.filter(**{'%s__%s'%(self.name, self.lookup_type):integers})
        return qs

class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):   
    ids = django_filters.IntegerListFilter(action=get_data)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('ids',)

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_class = MyFilter

def get_data(queryset, value):
    raise Exception(value)
```

Got idea from
[Possible to do an `in` `lookup_type` through the django-filter URL parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041639/possible-to-do-an-in-lookup-type-through-the-django-filter-url-parser?rq=1)