# Django: filter queryset by multiple ID

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My query is quite simple, I have a model `Vendor` in my Django REST app. What I want is to use a get response with a few ID and get back all the respective models with these ID. The GET url pattern could be something like this: `r'^api/vendors?id=1,2,3'`.

What I'm thinking of right now is to use `ListAPIView`, and in the `list` method filter my queryset with all the id in the url. But I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this (filtering queryset with a list of id, I'm very new to both Python and Django), so if anyone can provide any advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call django rest API with list of model ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278330/call-django-rest-api-with-list-of-model-ids)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*(Unfortunately I do not know django REST, so here is a pure django solution)*

Using the `ListAPIView` you can access the URL (or GET) params and modify the queryset.

```
class MyVendorView(ListAPIView):
    # attributes

    def get_queryset(self):
        id_string = self.request.GET.get('id')
        if id_string is not None:
            ids = [int(id) for id in id_string.split(',')]
            return Vendor.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

        else:
            return Vendor.objects.all()

    # other methods
```

*please note that I'm ingoring any attributes or other attributes needed*

#### What's happening here then?

- Overriding `get_queryset` will control what results we get from hitting the view
- `self.request.GET.get('id')` Will extract the value of the id query parameter from the url like so `localhost:8000/api/vendors?id=1,2,3` the result will be a string "1,2,3".
- `filter(id__in=ids)` lets you say select stuff that has an value in this **list** of ids