# Django 2.2+ call rest api, filtering on list of ids

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I use the `in` operator for filtering on a list of ids for the results of a ViewSet in the django rest framework?

A solution to the same question was found a few years ago ([Call django rest API with list of model ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278330/call-django-rest-api-with-list-of-model-ids)), however the accepted solution no longer works, and my viewset after tweaking for argument name changes only returns:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "ids": [
        "Enter a number."
    ]
}
```

Is there something that I have done incorrectly? My current attempt at an implementation looks like the following:

```
class ListFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value not in (None, ''):
            integers = [int(v) for v in value.split(',')]
            return qs.filter(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, self.lookup_type): integers})
        return qs


class MarkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ids = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="id", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Marker
        fields = ['ids']


class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Marker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MarkerFilter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is updated code fixing the problem. The accepted answer to the previous question had a few errors, and some argument names had changed, and with those changes reflected here id list filtering works as follows:

```
class ListFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value not in (None, ''):
            integers = [int(v) for v in value.split(',')]
            return qs.filter(**{'%s__%s' % (self.field_name, self.lookup_expr): integers})
        return qs


class MarkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ids = ListFilter(field_name="id", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Marker
        fields = ['ids']


class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Marker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MarkerFilter
```