# When using django-rest-framework, how can I filter django-taggit tags from a URL?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I'm looking to be able to use something similar to existing DRF search/filter funcitonality, `example.com/items/?tags=tag1,tag2,` or `?tags="tag 1","tag2",` or similar, to filter objects for a particular model by tags.

I *think* the best way to do this is by making a new filter, inheriting from `rest_framework.filters.BaseFilterBackend`, loosely following, `.SearchFilter`, but this is still somewhat beyond me.

I'd like to follow the [parsing rules Taggit uses](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html) if possible. I think the results should always be `.distinct`, but I'm not sure.

Where I'm at so far:

```
class TagFilter(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    tags_param = "tags"     # TODO Move to tag_filter_settings.TAGS_PARAM if this makes it to a package

    def get_tag_terms(self, request):
        params = request.query_params.get(self.tags_param, '')
        return params.replace(',', ' ').split()  # TODO replace with logic taggit uses to split

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        tag_fields = getattr(view, 'tag_fields', None)
        tag_terms = self.get_tag_terms(request)

        if not tag_fields or not tag_terms:
            return queryset

        # Exclude anything that doesn't link to tags matching all tag_terms
        # Against each of the tag_fields

    return queryset
```

Comment: I recommend using the [`django-filter`  package](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) as mentioned in [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).   I use this package and I love it.

Comment: I am using django-filter in this project, but couldn't figure out how to use it with django-taggit

Comment: Ah.  Perhaps this [question I asked 2 years ago may be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041639/possible-to-do-an-in-lookup-type-through-the-django-filter-url-parser). Short answer is that you probably do want to extend the base filter.  However, the link in that other question shows you how to generalize the sorting on list behavior.